# Understanding PDO Prepared Statements and Binding Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare, bindparam

From experience and also having been told constantly the benefits of using prepared statements and binding my parameters, I have constantly used those two techniques in my code, however I would like to understand exactly the purpose of each of those two techiques:

From my understanding of prepared statements:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ".$id;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

The previous code should create a sort of a buffer in the database with the query I proposed. Now **FROM MY UNDERSTANDING** (and I could be very wrong), the previous code is insecure, because the string `$sql` could be anything depending on what `$id` actually is, and if `$id` = `1; DROP TABLE myTable;--`, I would be inserting a malicious query even though I have a prepared statement.

**FROM MY UNDERSTANDING** this is where binding my parameters com in. If I do the following instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

The database should know exactly all the parts of the sql statement before hand:
`SELECT` these columns: `*`  `FROM myTable` and `WHERE id =` "a variable that was input by the user", and if `"a variable that was input by the user" != a variable`, the query fails.

I have been told by some my understanding is correct, and by others that it is false, could someone please let me know if I am wrong, correct, or missing something? And elaborate as much as you want, all feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first piece of code protects you from nothing as you are still passing `$id` which could come from `$_POST['id']` directly into the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly so my assumption would be correct that prepared statements need `bindParam()` to be secure?

Comment: You must use either `?,?` or your second  mechanism

Comment: Well you can also use `$stmt->execute( [':id' => $id] );` but that basically does the bind invisibly

Comment: @Webeng yes, prepared statements need bound params to be secure, and in most cases to even be useful. In your first example, you are preparing a query with something to the effect of "WHERE id = 5"; so it may help performance when running that exact query, but is of no benefit for the same query but `WHERE id = 4`. Preparing allows the server to parse the query once, rather than every time it is executed.

Comment: Maybe the bit about preparing statements you are also missing is that if you want to load data in a loop you can `->prepare()` once and `bind; execute()` many times. Thus compiling, and optimizing a query only once  but utilizing it 100 times

Comment: A prepared statement is a bit like creating a temporary Stored Proceedure. Once compiled cleanly, it can be used many times by just presenting a new set of variables to the stored proceedure. By temporary I mean it exists only for the lifetime of the connection i.e. the lifetime of one execution of your PHP script

Comment: One minor point: In your second example, if `$id` was `"1; DROP TABLE myTable;--"`, your query would not _fail_; it would execute successfully and return zero rows (unless myTable happened to have a row with an id of `"1; DROP TABLE myTable;--"`).

Comment: @RiggsFolly great point about optimizing the query and re-binding it for optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that the first case is insecure. It's important to understand though, that preparing a statement only has value if you are using variable data, and/or executing the same query repeatedly. If you are executing plain statements ***with no variables***, you could simply do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from myTable WHERE this_column IS NOT NULL";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

And end up with a `PDOStatement` object to work with, just like when you use `PDO::exec()`.

For your second case, again, you're largely correct. What's happening is the variable passed to the database is escaped and quoted (unless you specify otherwise with the third argument to `PDOStatement::bindParam()`, it's sent as a string which is fine for most cases.) So, the query won't "fail" if bad data is sent. It behaves exactly as if you had passed a valid number that didn't exist as an ID in the database. There are, of course, [some edge cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection) where you are still vulnerable even with a correctly prepared statement.

Also, to make life easier, you can use prepared statements like this, to do implicit binding:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([":id"=>$id]);
```

Or even like this, with un-named parameters:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$id]);
```

Naturally, most of this has been explained in the comments while I was typing up the answer!